# custom AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Can anyone please help with this requirement .

I have an Autocompletetextview in form . I am displaying business names in drop down list . its working fine with this, but now i need to show the location(eg: hyderabad,Andhra Pradesh ,India) like so below the business name of a list item . so that text typed should match only with the business names and not the location .

Main thing here is Autocomplete should be done with business names and not with location hint.

What should i do now . Plz its urgent

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For This You can create your own Custom adapter by Extending the base adapter..
And create a layout of your row design....And pass the location array to the adapter rather than passing the Buisness name API...